# DFS to get all possible solutions?

Tags: recursion, backtracking

I have these Circles:

[image: Circles]

I want to get the list of all possible solution of maximum non-intersecting circles. This is the illustration of the solution I wanted from node A.

[image]

Therefore the possible solutions from node A:
1 = [A,B,C], 2 = [A,B,E], 3 = [A,C,B], 4 = [A,E,B] ..etc

I want to store all of the possibilities into a list, which the will be used for weighting and selecting the best result. However, I'm still trying to create the list of all possibilities.

I've tried to code the structure here, however I still confused about backtracking and recursive. Anyone could help here?

```
# List of circle
# List of circle
list_of_circle = ['A','B','C','D','E']
# List of all possible solutions
result = []
# List of possible nodes
ways = []

for k in list_of_circle:
    if len(list_of_circle)==0:
        result.append(ways)
    else:
        ways.append[k]
        list_of_circle.remove(k)
        for j in list_of_circle:
            if k.intersects(j):
                 list_of_circle.remove(j)
return result
```

Comment: `[A, B, E]`, `[A, E, B]`? Is it supposed to repeat a result?

Comment: Yes, in the end I don't want any repeated result. However I think it will become even complex to exclude the repeated result. Therefore I'll delete the repeated ones after being stored at the list. Or is it possible to do it concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (pseudocode).

```
def get_max_non_intersect(selected_circles, current_circle_idx, all_circles):
    if current_circle_idx == len(all_circles):  # final case
        return selected_circles

    # we recursively get the biggest selection of circles if the current circle is not selected
    list_without_current_circle = get_max_non_intersect(selected_circles, current_circle_idx + 1, all_circles)

    # now we check if we can add the current circle to the ones selected
    current_intersects_selected = false
    current_circle = all_circles[current_circle_idx]
    for selected_circle in selected_circles:
        if intersects(current_circle, selected_circle):
            current_intersects_selected = true
            break

    if current_intersects_selected is true:  # we cannot add the current circle
        return list_without_current_circle
    else:   # we can add the current circle
        list_with_current_circle = get_max_non_intersect(selected_circles + [current_circle], current_circle_idx + 1, all_circles)
        return list_with_current_circle + list_without_current_circle
```